# Possibility load Angular js page with AJAX?

Tags: angularjs

I have a main page like this:

index.html

```
<div id="ajaxContent"></div>
<button onclick="callAjax()">Click</button>
<script>
function callAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "angular.html",
            data: data,            
            success: function (response) {
                $("#ajaxContent").html(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And in angular.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>angular.module("myApp").controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scopr.test="hello!";
});
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{test}}
</div>
```

but after loading by ajax always says "angular is not defined" is there any way to do this?thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would say, no need use jQuery for AJAX when you can use the angular's $http service.
If you want to load the whole html file based on some condition you can use a directive or angular's routing.

In my opinion it's wrong to try doing it this way, what are you trying to achieve?

I am quite sure that your problem with angular not being defined comes from the fact that you don't put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>` in the page where you are trying to insert this HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually the index.html page is not my own,and some one uses my .js file include in page,and call a ajax function load content like "index.html" above so this part of content is also dynamically.

Comment: I'm not sure that is going to work, don't really have any other suggestions, sorry.